# JDBC Statement/PreparedStatement per connection

Tags: java, jdbc

I was wondering how many statements or preparedstatements can be opened per connection at the same time. I don't really understand how would it work if multiple statements get executed and multiple resultssets are retrieved. Links of resources with details would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Multiple statements can be created and used on the same connection, but only *one* resultset at once can be created and used on the same statement. If you create/open another one by the same statement, then any previously opened resultset will be implicitly closed, leading to "ResultSet closed" exceptions on any attempt to access it.

Comment: As far as I know only one ResultSet can be created per *statement*, not per connection. This is supported by the [description of Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html): 'By default, only one ResultSet object per Statement object can be open at the same time. Therefore, if the reading of one ResultSet object is interleaved with the reading of another, each must have been generated by different Statement objects.'