# JDBC ResultSet closed statement

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

I'm trying to write a function that updates 2 tables in my database. I'm getting an error which i think is caused by calling next() on a resultset that has no more rows in the set. 
I was thinking an if condition on hasNext() would fix this but it's not available to the result set...

The error i'm getting is 'No operations allowed after statement closed.'

```
private void updateDatabase() throws Exception {
        Connection conn = getConnection();
        PreparedStatement updateMovieStmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO movies VALUES(null,?,null,null,null)", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        PreparedStatement updateVideoStmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO video_files VALUES(null,null,null,?,?)", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        try {
            for (Movie localMovie : getLocalMovies()) {
                // fetch a local movie{
                boolean newMovie = true;
                for (Movie dbMovie : getDatabaseMovies(conn)) {
                    newMovie = true;
                    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(localMovie.getTitlePattern(), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
                    Matcher m = p.matcher(dbMovie.getTitle());
                    // if it's already in the database not new movie... but is
                    // is it a new video rip????????????;
                    if (m.find()) {
                        System.out.println("DB movie: " + dbMovie.getTitle() + " matches localpattern of: " + localMovie.getTitlePattern());
                        newMovie = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (newMovie == true && localMovie.getTitle() != null) {
                    updateMovieStmt.setString(1, localMovie.getTitle());
                    updateMovieStmt.executeUpdate();
                    // get new movie id and put into new video row
                    ResultSet rs = updateMovieStmt.getGeneratedKeys();
                    if (rs.next()) {
                        updateVideoStmt.setBytes(1, localMovie.getHash());
                        updateVideoStmt.setInt(2, rs.getInt(1));
                        updateVideoStmt.executeUpdate();
                    }

                }

            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            updateMovieStmt.close();
            updateVideoStmt.close();
            conn.close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using batches (`addBatch()`/`executeBatch()`), nor clearing the parameters (`clearParameters()`), then you should be creating the statements inside the loop, not outside the loop.

Move the both `conn.prepareStatement()` lines into the `if (newMovie == true && localMovie.getTitle() != null)` block, preferably refactored in separate methods. Your current method is doing way too much.

Comment: [Check your this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149135/jdbc-statement-preparedstatement-per-connection)

Comment: thanks, do you think updateMovie(Connection conn, String title) updateVideo.... would be a suitable solution?

Comment: "You can have only one open Statement at once per connection. Once you create a new Statement on the same connection and execute it, the previously created one will be closed." - "you can have only one open statement at a time. Once you create a new one, the previous one will be closed." - **Both these statements are wrong.** [The correct answer is in a comment by Mark Rotteveel here.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5150085/269126)

Comment: @BalusC: you could take Lumi's advice and edit this answer. It has shaken me quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

> you can have only one open Statement per connection. Once you create a new Statement on the same connection, the previously created one will be closed

This holds true for resultSet that we can have only one resultSet open per statement. With a connection we can have multiple statements open.

Comment: Whether an answer to the OP's concrete problem or not, it is related, and the statements mady by @sudmong are correct.