# jdbc statement connection

Tags: sql, jdbc, connection

QUESTION: can YOU use multiple statements and recordset, which operate simultaneously, using the same connection in a non MULTI THREAD?

I only found this question which interests me, but the answer is not consistent.

[JDBC Statement/PreparedStatement per connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149135/jdbc-statement-preparedstatement-per-connection)

The answer explain the relationship between recordset and statement, which is known to me.

Given that, you can not have multiple recordsets for statement

The answer says that you can have multiple recordsets for connection. But they are not mentioned any other sources.

---

**I'm asking if it's possible to loop over the first recordset, then using the same connection (used to generate first recordset) to open another recordset use it looping in iteration. And where is the documentation that define this behavior?**

---

The situation that interests me is like this, the statement perform tasks simultaneously ins

```
Connection con = Factory.getDBConn (user, pss, endpoint, etc);
Statement stmt = con.createStatement ();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery ("SELECT TEXT FROM dba");

while (rs.next ()) {
 rs.getInt (....
 rs.getInt (....
 rs.getInt (....
 rs.getInt (....

 Statement stmt2 con.createStatement = ();
 ResultSet rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery ("iSelect ......");
 while (rs2.next ()) {
 ....
 rs2.close ();
 stm2.close ();

 Statement stmt3 con.createStatement = ();
 ResultSet rs3 = stmt3.executeQuery ("Insert Into table xxx ......");
 ....
 rs3.close ();
 stm3.close ();
}
```

---

To clarify a bit more: with the execution of update in stmt3, you could obtain an error like this:

java.sql.SQLException: There is an open result set on the current connection, which must be closed prior to executing a query.

So you can't mix SQL in the same connection.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a question here. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: Yes there isn't a Question Mark.... Anyway. I'm asking if it's possible to loop over the first recordset, then using the same connection (used to generate first recordset) to open another recordset use it and continue in iteration. And where is the documentation that define this behavior?

Comment: Yes, that's possible, provided you aren't trying to use the same Statement to create the record sets (which, in the code in the question, you aren't).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to work with two (or more) resultsets simmultaneously within a single method.

It is possible, and it works well. But you have to remember a few things:

- Everything you do on each recordset is handled by a single `Connection`, unless you declare new connections for each `Statement` (and `ResultSet`)
- If you need to do a multithreaded process, I suggest you to create a `Connection` for each thread (or use a connection pool); if you use a single connection in a multithreaded process, your program will hang or crash, since every SQL statement goes through a single connection, and every new statement has to wait until the previous one has finnished.

Besides that, your question needs some clarification. What do you really need to do?

Comment: "and every new statement has to wait until the previous one has finnished" so the code that i have defined can't work because statement stmt2 hangs waiting stmt ?.

Comment: @user1594895 the code block you write is executed sequentially, so your SQL instructions are not executed simultaneously... The observation I made applies only if you perform your tasks using multiple threads

Comment: @user1594895 also remember to close the `ResultSet` and `Statement` objects (and, of course, the `Connection` object) when you are done with them

Answer (score 0):

A ResultSet object is automatically closed when the Statement object that generated it is closed, re-executed, or used to retrieve the next result from a sequence of multiple results.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html

Comment: A ResultSet object is automatically closed when the Statement object that generated it is closed, re-executed, or used to retrieve the next result from a sequence of multiple results.
That is why we can't have multiple recordsets for statement but i'm asking "statement per connection"

Comment: You can have multiple statements per connection. In a non-multithreaded application, everything is executed in a sequence => you cant execute 2 statements a time.

Answer (score -1):

SQL Server is a database that does support multiple record sets. So you can exceute a couple of queries in a single stored procedure for example

```
SELECT * FROM employees
SELECT * FROM products
SELECT * FROM depts
```

You can then move between each record set. At least I know you can do this in .Net for example

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("connstring"))
using (var command = new SqlCommand("SPName", conn))
{
    conn.Open();
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    var (reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
       while(reader.Read())
       {
           //Process all records from first result set
       }
       reader.Next();
       while(reader.Read())
       {
           //Process all records from 2nd result set
       }
       reader.Next();
       while(reader.Read())
       {
              //Process all records from 3rd result set
        }
     }
}
```

I am assuming that java would support a similar mechanism

Comment: Thanks for the snippet, the situation you describe is reported in this MS code http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378758.aspx, Anyway I need the data in the first recrodset to perform the second one